# angular 2, when i am using routing in my project then error show in console window

Tags: angular, routes

EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./e class e - inline template:9:6 caused by: object unsubscribed
Error: Error in ./e class e - inline template:9:6 caused by: object unsubscribed
    at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:811:33)

// aap.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
// import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <div class="container">
                <div class="punjab-vehicle-wrapper">
                    <div class="punjab-vehicle">
                        <a routerLink="/province" routerLinkActive="active" > Province Vehicle Verification </a>
                        <a routerLink="/capital"> Capital Vehicle Verification </a>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})

export class AppComponent{

}
```

// routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

// loading _component
import { VehicleComponent } from './vehicle.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { IslamVehicleComponent } from './islam-vehicle.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    // { path: 'main', component: AppComponent },
    // { path: '', redirectTo: '/punjab', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'province', component: VehicleComponent },
    { path: 'capital', component: IslamVehicleComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]

})

export class VehicleRoutingModule{

}
```

I don't know in which file error is,

Comment: Show us some code, its hard to debug air...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably you can't import your new component in app.module.ts.

[Scotch Example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-angular-2-single-page-apps-with-the-component-router)

### Try to fix on your code

- app.component.ts

  `import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: <template Code>
  })
   export class AppComponent {}`
- app-routing.module.ts

  `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
   import { AppComponent } from './AppComponent.component';
   const appRoutes: Routes = [ {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/main',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    }, {
      path: 'main',
      component: AppComponent
     }];
   @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
      })
     export class AppRoutingModule {}`
- app.module.ts

  `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
  import { AppComponent } from './AppComponent.component';
  import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
  @NgModule({
    imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       FormsModule,
       ReactiveFormsModule,
       HttpModule,
       AppRoutingModule
    ],
  declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule {}`

  ### Hopefully it's work!